# Setting a session using jquery without page reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem, how can I set a session using jquery(AJAX) without page refresh.My problem is the session is not set unless I press on the refresh button so as to set the session.My php page is separate from my jquery code. This is a login function am trying to implement
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. No quick and easy solution comes to mind.

How about starting the session when the user enters the site, and having the log-in process amend the running session with the information that it now belongs to a logged in user?